# An inequality for expectation of square root of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

I saw this somewhere  and I do not know how to prove it:$$ E(\sqrt{X})\approx \sqrt{E(X)}\bigg(1-\frac{Var(X)}{8E(X)^2}\bigg) ,
$$ for any random varibel concentrated aroud its mean.Could somebody kindly help

Comment: Try Taylor theorem, $\sqrt{x} \approx \sqrt{\mu} + \frac{(x-\mu) }{2\sqrt{\mu}} - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{8 \sqrt{\mu^3}}.$ (The statistician call this delta-approximation in lieu of Taylor theorem, because they can.)

Comment: Lots of thanks William M.